# JQuery Querybuilder json parser in java | http://querybuilder.js.org/

Tags: java, jquery, json, expression, mvel

I want build a UI to create boolean expressions and for that I am planning to use [JQuery querybuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/). This plugin/framework gives me the json data of the query formed in the UI.

I want to parse this json and convert it into boolean expression in Java. The site mentions three parsers that are developed in other programming languages.

1. .NET  castle-it / [dynamic-linq-query-builder](https://github.com/castle-it/dynamic-linq-query-builder)
2. PHP  fourlabsldn / [QBJSParser](https://github.com/fourlabsldn/QBJSParser) & [QBJSParserBundle](https://github.com/fourlabsldn/QBJSParserBundle)
3. Rails  SixiS / [jquery_query_builder-rails](https://github.com/SixiS/jquery_query_builder-rails)

I want similar parser in Java that can parse this json data and return a boolean expression as a string and evaluate it using the Java Mvel framework. I searched a lot but could not find any.

Comment: soo, just write one? Parsing the json: https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/ or use the GSON libraries. Then it's a matter of evaluatig the the data you have. I'm not going to write it for  just 50 points, but you should be able to relatively fast. Most of the logic in the .net one you can transpose to java easely.

Comment: Thanks! I know how to parse json, I just wanted to know if there are already any libs for this or may be some pointers.

Comment: @Rakesh did you find any package in Java which does what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another JavaScript library that gives the expression.

https://github.com/gantir/jsexpbuilder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://github.com/itfsw/QueryBuilder? This takes JQuery QueryBuilder JSON and transforms it to SQL or MongoDB expressions. You could extend this to build MVEL, probably taking the SQL builder as a template and using custom parsers where MVEL and SQL deviate (e.g. AND => &&).